# Lags with Kivy Screenmanager and RecycleView

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, raspberry-pi3

I am using the Screenmanager to show 6 different screens to the user. To show database values I created a datagrid with the help of RecycleView. The Grid looks like this:

[image]

Unfortunately when the user select the "Measure" screen, it takes some seconds to show the datagrid or it lags showing the grid. Also when user is selecting a row it takes up to 2 seconds to show the screen behind. If the user is clicking on different screens which contains also a lot of stuff the GUI is running fluently. The GUI is running on my RaspberryPi 3 with a touchscreen. If the App is running the Raspberry hardware is not really busy, so it won't be a problem of hardware power.

The kv-File:

```
<SelectableButtonGridMeasure>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.19, 0.35, 0.45, 1) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: 'icons/bkgrd-down-color.png'
    background_color: 0.25, 0.24, 0.33, 70
    on_press: app.root.ids.scr_mngr.current = 'screenmeasuringtask'


Wsrmescreenmeasure:

<Wsrmescreenmeasure>:
    id: wsrmescreen_measure_kv
    grid_measuring_task: grid_kvmeasuring_task

    padding: 30
    spacing: 10

    viewclass: 'SelectableButtonGridMeasure'
    SelectableRecycleGridLayoutMeasure:
        id: grid_kvmeasuring_task
        default_size: None, dp(35)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: False
        cols: 5
        markup: True
```

Adding data to the grid:

```
    # Put data to datagrid in screenmeasure
    Wsrmescreenmeasure.data = temp_data

    # Update inserted data in data grid    
    Wsrmescreenmeasure.refresh_from_data(App.get_running_app().
            root.ids.screenmeasure_kv.grid_measuring_task.recycleview)
```

Datagrid creation:

```
# Datagrid measure
class Wsrmescreenmeasure(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Wsrmescreenmeasure, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # Design datagrid for measuring tasks
        self.data = w_logic.WsrmeLogic.get_data(self)
```

What could be the reason for this lags? If I reduce the content of the datagrid (e.g. from 10 to 5 rows) I feel like it's going a little bit faster. I measured the time to fill in data etc. with decorators but I haven't found a clue.

Comment: I would put the part where it gets the data in a thread, and only update UI in main. That way the app will respond all the time. Then you could check if the lag is from the database or not.

Comment: @el3ien the data is not inserted when user selecting screenmeasure. Data will be updated every 10 seconds after selecting the screen. So at first start there will be no data shown but the lag is still there

Comment: ok, it is a little difficoult to see from here why this lags. But this line `self.data = w_logic.WsrmeLogic.get_data(self)` is running at instantiation, and in the main thread.

Comment: Yes that's true, but even when there is no data added, the lag occures :-/

Comment: even when you remove that line?

Comment: Yes. When I delete that line nothing changes except the data is inserted to the grid some seconds later

Comment: Which line do you get the data?

Comment: Here:

    `# Put data to datagrid in screenmeasure
    Wsrmescreenmeasure.data = temp_data

    # Update inserted data in data grid    
    Wsrmescreenmeasure.refresh_from_data(App.get_running_app().
            root.ids.screenmeasure_kv.grid_measuring_task.recycleview)`